# Why covariance matrix estimated pairwise is not guaranteed to be PSD?

Tags: pca, covariance, covariance-matrix, eigenvalues

As mentioned here 
[Is a covariance matrix composed of matrixes derived from separate samples guaranteed to be positive definitive?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146687/is-a-covariance-matrix-composed-of-matrixes-derived-from-separate-samples-guaran)
and here [Must a matrix of sample pairwise covariances be PSD?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350852/must-a-matrix-of-sample-pairwise-covariances-be-psd) 
if you set up a covariance matrix by plugging in pairwise covariances, then it is not guaranteed to be PSD (positive semi-definite). My questions are:

1. Is it also the case if you don`t have NaN values ?
2. What is the mathematical reason why covariance matrix becomes non-PSD if estimated pairwise ?

Thank you